# TempDB Contention with 24 physical tempdb files on 48 core AMD Opteron box

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I just received the following notification about an instance of SQL Server 2005.  The instance has a core-to-tempdb-file ratio of 2:1 for a total tempdb file count of 24 files.  Contention should not be happening - how would I detect the source of this contention?  TempDB and all other databases are on SAN storage via 10 GB Ethernet.  The SAN has 46 10k SAS drives configured in one RAID-60 array.  This array is shared with several VMWare servers and an Exchange server or two.

Notification from Idera SQL Diagnostic Manager:

11/8/2012 10:49:00 PM, Tempdb Contention (ms) on MGSQL01 is Critical.

Tempdb latch contention has been detected on MGSQL01. The total wait time detected is 1782 milliseconds. This is an indication that performance is being impacted by contention on allocation maps in tempdb. If this is a regular problem it may be alleviated by following best practices with respect to tempdb file count, size, and IO subsystem.

PFS Wait Time: 1782 ms GAM Wait Time: 0 ms SGAM Wait Time: 0 ms

Tempdb Contention (ms): Current wait time for tempdb allocation maps (GAM, SGAM, and PFS), in milliseconds. This alert may only be raised on instances running SQL 2005 or above.

Comment: Heya Max, just a couple of quick questions.  I had to deal with a similar issue very recently.

-Is it pagelatch_SH or pageiolatch_SH?  I'm pretty sure it's pagelatch_SH in your case but I just want to be certain.

-Have you used extended events to track which queries are accumulating the most PAGELATCH_SH wait times?

Can you also please post your top 20 wait stats from 
SELECT * FROM SYS.DM_OS_WAIT_STATS ORDER BY 3

What's perfmon telling you?  Is the TempDB drive in fact experiencing any real IO contention?  Spike in MS?

Comment: Are the waits on a PFS page in a particular file or all of them? Are all of the tempdb files of equal size? Do you know what kind/size of objects are being allocated in tempdb? Are temporary tables being explicitly truncated and dropped by app code? Have you thought about implementing trace flag 1118?

Comment: Hi Max, have a look here http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2011/04/21/analyzing-tempdb-contention-a-month-of-activity-monitoring-part-21-of-30.aspx

Comment: Are the tempdb files set to autogrow?  I discovered a similar issue on a server and made sure the sizes were fixed.  No more error.

Comment: Are you running trace flag 1118?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, @ThomasKejser - I had to check.  No, TF1118 was not in use.  TF1117, for data file autogrowth, was however.  I say was, because we are no longer using that particular server for SQL Server.

Comment: @MaxVernon: As a rule of thumb, always run T1118. There really is no reason to run without it

Comment: In fact I'd turn off 1117 and go with 1118 (https://twitter.com/PaulRandal/status/179565326067961856)

Comment: @swasheck - I wrote a Connect item asking MS to modify the behavior of 1117.  http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/781198/trace-flag-1117-autogrowth-of-data-files-is-instance-wide-would-like-a-flag-for-just-tempdb

Comment: @maxvernon my impression is that they did and they called it 1118

Comment: @swasheck T1118 disabled SGAM allocation in Tempdb and forces GAM allocation. T1117 on the other hand does something else. If you have a filegroup with multiple files, instead of autogrowing file by file, SQL Server will autogrow all files in the filegroup.

Comment: @maxvernon, I +1 your connect item. Nice one.

Comment: @EdwardDortland thank you for the explanation

Comment: @MaxVernon also, 1782ms latch wait time is cumulative. are you actually able to trace pfs contention? periodically check `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` to see if you can catch something in the act ... some sort of variation of `select * 
 from sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks
 where resource_description like '2:1:%'
  and wait_type Like 'PAGE%LATCH_%'`
also, tf1118 will still help with pfs contention since it has to be scanned to determine which extents can/will be allocated.

Comment: @swasheck - unfortunately I don't have access to this machine anymore (it's been decommissioned) - I will however keep this in mind for future!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trace flag 1118 forces uniform extent allocations instead of mixed page allocations.   The trace flag is commonly used to assist in TEMPDB scalability by avoiding SGAM and other allocation contention points. If you have SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2005 and the fix applied and are still encountering TEMPDB contention consider trace flag 1118 for further assistance in resolving the contention.

Comment: Could you explain, preferably with an example, how changing from single page shared allocation to dedicated extent allocation will solve PFS contention?